# How can i connect facebook and update status

Tags: facebook-graph-api, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have examined **Facebook Modul** on this [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook)

I would like to post message to facebook but I don't connect facebook with below code on Android and iOS simulator too.

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = "55xxxxxxxxxx";
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream'];
// Permissions your app needs
fb.authorize();

fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', {message: "Trying out FB Graph API and it's fun!"}, 
         "POST", function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unkown result");
        }
    }
});
```

I have just created an app on Facebook's http://developer.facebook.com page

**Should i use Add Platform button on Facebook Developer setting tab?**

If answer is yes. How can i fill

Facebook Plaform's iOS `Bundle ID` `iPhone Store ID` `iPad Store ID`

Facebook Plaform's Android `Package Name` `Class Name` `Key Hashes`

My app is not published on market. It is test case yet.

My Titanium SDK is `3.2.3GA` and i am testing it on `iOS 7.1 simulator`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an event listener to facebook login event like this :

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = "55xxxxxxxxxx";
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream'];
// Permissions your app needs
fb.authorize();
fb.addEventListener("login", function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', {
            message : "Trying out FB Graph API   and it's fun!"
        }, "POST", function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
                alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
            } else {
                if (e.error) {
                    alert(e.error);
                } else {
                    alert("Unkown result");
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unkown result");
        }
    }
});
```